# Django get list of objects matching a criteria on or before a given date

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I am using DJango 1.10, and have this model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ClientStatusHistory(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(to=User, related_name="status_history")
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(db_index=True)
```

The table records when a user was marked as active or inactive.

I want to select a list of users that were active on a given date.

How do I do that using the django ORM?
Sorry if the question is worded poorly; basically I am writing function like so:
`get_users_active_on_date(date_value)`

Here is a trivial example:
Lets say my system has just one user with Id 1. The user was active from jan 1st to mar 20th. Then on mar 20th, he was marked as inactive. And on May 15th, he was active again.

So, the table will have 3 entries:

```
(1, Jan 1st, True),
(1, Mar 20th, False),
(1, May 15th, True)
```

So if I query for the date Mar 1st, it should return me [1], because the user 1 was active during that time.

Whereas if I query for Mar 30th, it should return me [] since the user was inactive.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, what you're asking for can be done like this:

```
today = timezone.now().date()
result = ClientStatusHistory.objects.filter(date__date=today, status=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

But with 'advanced' queries like that, it could be useful to do that with the help of [Django Querysets and Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/), especially uf you're going to use it in multiple places (DRY! : ):

```
class ClientStatusHistoryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def users_active_on_date(self, d):
        return self.filter(date__date=d, status=True).values_list('id', flat=True)

class ClientStatusHistory(models.Model):
    ...

    objects = ClientStatusHistoryQuerySet.as_manager()

...

today = timezone.now().date()
result = ClientStatusHistory.objects.users_active_on_date(today)
```

Comment: This will not work, because the date stored is not the date I am querying on.